# ajax form with many to many (array) Input

Tags: asp.net, ajax, many-to-many

I have a Db with Movies and Genres (Many to Many) and I want to display different properties in a table. I struggle to display the genre names with ajax. This is the input I get from my Db.

```
 {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Superman",
        "originalTitel": "Superman - Der Film",
        "releseDate": "1978-05-15T00:00:00",
        "duration": 137,
        "description": "Superman ist ein Science-Fiction-Film aus dem Jahr 1978 und zugleich der erste Teil der erfolgreichen Comicverfilmungen um die Geschichte des von Jerry Siegel und Joe Shuster geschaffenen Comichelden Superman.",
        "rating": null,
        "personalRating": null,
        "ageRestrictionId": 4,
        "ageRestriction": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "USK 12"
        },
        "genres": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Action",
                "isChecked": false
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Crime",
                "isChecked": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

And this is the ajax Form I have at the moment. It works with the movie name, age restriction and the delete but I don´t know how I can get the genre names out of the array.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#movies").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/movies",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "name",
                    render: function (data, type, movie) {
                        return "<a href='/customers/edit/" + movie.id + "'>" + movie.name + "</a>";
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: "duration",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return data + " Minuten"
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: "ageRestriction.name"
                },
                {
                    data: ???
                },
                {
                    data: "id",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return "<button class='btn-link js.delete' data-customer-id=" + data + ">Löschen</button>";
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

I tried different things and nothing really worked. As I´m new to ajax I have the feeling I´m using it a bit wrong for the array case.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to

```
{ 
  "data": "[, ].name"
}
```

> [] - Array notation. DataTables can automatically combine data from an
>   array source, joining the data with the characters provided between
>   the two brackets. For example: name[, ] would provide a comma-space
>   separated list from the source array. If no characters are provided
>   between the brackets, the original array source is returned.